# How to pass the map variable to the external function like eval and invoke in marklogic xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

`xdmp:eval($s, (), "world"))`

Instead of default value as second parameter from the above code, i want to pass map as the parameter to the external function.

Comment: Your example code doesn't look correct. You are passing an empty sequence for the `$vars` and the string "world" as the `$options` and have an extra parenthesis. If modeling from the examples, likely meant to post `xdmp:eval($s, (xs:QName("my:x"), "world"))` and then it might be more clear what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

If `$s` has e.g. `declare variable $v1 external;` in the prolog then I think you can use `xdmp:eval($s, map:new(map:entry('{}v1', some-expression)))`, or, as pointed out in a comment, even `xdmp:eval($s, map:new(map:entry('v1', some-expression)))` to pass the result of evaluating `some-expression` as the value of the variable `$v1` e.g. `xdmp:eval($s, map:new(map:entry('v1', 'foo')))` passes in the string value `foo`.

Comment: You can omit the `{}` in the key name with non-prefixed variables.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the documentation for [`xdmp:eval()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval) you can either pass a sequence of alternating QName and value, or you can pass a map.

> External variable values to make available to the evaluated code, expressed as either a sequence of alternating QName-value pairs, or a `map:map`.
>
> - If you use a sequence, it must contain alternating variable QNames and values. e.g. `(xs:QName("var1"), "val1", xs:Qname("var2"), "val2")`.
> - If you use a map, then each key is a string representing the Clark notation of the variable QName ("{namespaceURI}localname"), and its value is the corresponding variable value. You can use [`xdmp:key-from-QName`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:key-from-QName) to generate the Clark notation to use as a key.

The example from `xdmp:eval()` documentation shows how to invoke with the sequence:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace my='http://mycompany.com/test';

let $s :=
      "xquery version '1.0-ml';
       declare namespace my='http://mycompany.com/test';
       declare variable $my:x as xs:string external;
       declare variable $my:y as xs:string external := 'goodbye';
       concat('hello ', $my:x, ' ', $my:y)"
return
    (: evaluate the query string $s using the variables
       supplied as the second parameter to xdmp:eval :)
    xdmp:eval($s, (xs:QName("my:x"), "world"))
```

So, instead of `(xs:QName("my:x"), "world")` you need to create a `map:map` and create an entry with the key of the QName as Clark notation: `{http://mycompany.com/test}x` and the value "world" for that entry.

The way to invoke with a `map:map` would be:

```
let $vars := map:new() => map:with(xdmp:key-from-QName(xs:QName("my:x")), "world")
return
  xdmp:eval($s, $vars)
```

Comment: General note: it saves some hassle if you don't prefix your variable names. An external variable named `$x` can be referenced with `map:entry('x', 'world')`.