# Passing variable to xdmp:eval Marklogic Xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I need to pass an argument into an xdmp:eval with xquery:

```
let $uri :="/tmp/myDoc.csv"

let $doc:= xdmp:eval('fn:doc($uri)' , (),  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>{xdmp:database("My-Database")}</database></options>) 

return $doc
```

But i'm getting `Undefined variable $uri`

I need to do this with an xdmp:eval for many reasons, have any one any idea how to do this in xquery ?

Comment: See the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147584/how-to-pass-the-map-variable-to-the-external-function-like-eval-and-invoke-in-ma, the query string needs the declare the variable.

Comment: Also, `xdmp:eval` is generally not your best option. Look to use `xdmp:invoke-function()` instead. It is safer, and easier. https://www.marklogic.com/blog/first-class-functions/

Comment: @MadsHansen I tried the xdmp:invoke-function() , that resolve my issue , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you eval that string, it has no context to know that the `$uri` value should be.
You can pass those context values in the second parameter when you invoke:

```
let $uri :="/tmp/myDoc.csv"
let $doc:= xdmp:eval('fn:doc($uri)', 
                     (xs:QName("uri"), $uri),  
                     <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
                       <database>{xdmp:database("My-Database")}</database>
                     </options>) 
return $doc
```

But you should consider using [`xdmp:invoke-function()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:invoke-function) instead, with the anonymous function:

```
let $uri := "/tmp/myDoc.csv"
xdmp:invoke-function(function(){ fn:doc($uri) }, 
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <database>{xdmp:database("My-Database")}</database>
  </options>
)
```

It [is generally easier and safer](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/first-class-functions/) to use `xdmp:invoke-function`.